# Why C++ friendship for function inside a class does not work same as a standalone function?

Tags: c++, compilation, friend

**I want to know why one of the following two codes compiles while the other does not.** In the first code, createB is a stand alone function. In the second code the function createB is a member of class A.

The first one compiles.

```
#include <iostream>

class A;

class B {
public:
  B() { std::cout << "B"; }
  friend B createB();
};

class A {
public:
  A() { std::cout << "A"; }

};

B createB() { return B(); }

int main() {
  A a;
  B b = createB();
}
```

The second one does not.

```
#include <iostream>

class A;

class B {
public:
  B() { std::cout << "B"; }
  friend B A::createB();
};

class A {
public:
  A() { std::cout << "A"; }

  B createB() { return B(); }
};

int main() {
  A a;
  B b = a.createB();
}
```

Comment: In the 2nd example, `A` is incomplete at the point of the friend declaration `friend B A::createB();`. To solve this move the definition of `A` to before `B` so that `A` is complete at the point of the friend declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### Case 1

In the first snippet, `createB` is a free(standalone) function and it is not mandatory that the friend declaration names an existing function. So this works and also implicitly declares a function named `createB` with return type of `B` in the global namespace, though this `createB` is not visible through ordinary lookup.

##### Case 2

The **problem** in the 2nd example is that `A` is an **incomplete** at the point of the friend declaration `friend B A::createB();`.

To *solve* this, we can move the definition of `A` to before `B` so that `A` is **complete** at the point of the friend declaration. Additionally, we can provide the definition of `createB` after `B` has been defined as shown below:

```
//forward declaration so that B can be used in declaration B createB();
class B;

class A {
public:
  A() { std::cout << "A"; }
  //this is declaration
  B createB();
};

class B {
public:
  B() { std::cout << "B"; }
  friend B A::createB();    //this works as now at this point A is complete since we moved the definition of A to before B
};

//this is definition 
B A::createB() { return B(); }
int main() {
  A a;
  B b = a.createB();
}
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/THatWK7yF)